# Uploading an image (base64 string) to Web API as filestream

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, upload, image-upload

What I need to do: I have a web page that uses the webcam to capture a photo. When you click a button, it saves the current webcam image to an HTML canvas object. When I get the image from the canvas object, it comes out as a Base64 encoded string, e.g.

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAABwCAYAAAD8HIl9AAAgAElEQVR4Xky9B7hld3Hl...

On the other end is a Web API service used to save the photo to the server. It is written in C# and is expecting a FileStream.

My front end is written using only HTML and Javascript (Angular/Jquery included). I need to send the image to the server in the format it expects.

I've been banging my head against the wall for two days. It seems that what I need to do is create a FormData object, append the image to it, and send it up. But doing so gives me a 200 error. Something is not formed correctly.

While I use an input element of type file, and upload a file from disk, this code works perfectly. When when I pass it the base64 image string, it fails. When I append the image string to a FormData object, it fails.

```
factory.setPhoto = function (id, image) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', image);
    return $http.post(baseUrl + '/' + id, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    }).then(function (results) {
        // whatever
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the base64 data component to raw binary data and then pass it through formdata. Try out one of the solution in this post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5100158/1980415